# How to parse wikipedia's JSON data in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, wikipedia

```
pages =     {
    328000 =         {
        extract = "<p><b>Advil</b> is a brand of ibuprofen, a nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drug (NSAID).</p>";
        ns = 0;
        pageid = 328000;
        title = Advil;
    };
}

NSDictionary *first=[json objectForKey:@"query"];
NSDictionary *second=[first objectForKey:@"pages"];
```

How to parse the above JSON data which comes from wikipedia API? I Know how to parse it but here the problem is the key after pages "328000" is dynamic and is unknown until it is retrieved. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code and better explain what issue you are having with the code.

Comment: com'mon i don't know why it is downvoted even though i have explained the problem. The problem is how to access it but not in my code.

Comment: The last sentence of your comment makes no sense. How else would you access it other than using code in your app? As I said, post your relevant code and explain what issue you are having with it.

Comment: [Based on MediaWiki's documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats), it looks like there are always some known keys to check for. Please be more specific in your question, and as @rmaddy said, post whatever code you are using currently to parse the JSON.

Comment: edited. I used dictionaries.

Comment: Iterate the keys in `second`.

Comment: could you please give me an example?I am new to Objective C.

Comment: Example: You have an array int a [10]. You can access a [0], a [1], a [2], .... How would you access arbitrary array elements? How would you do the same thing in a dictionary?

Comment: but here second is not an array to iterate it.

Comment: The above is not valid JSON.  It's not even a valid NSLog dump of an NSDictionary.

Comment: And read the documentation!!!

Comment: @hotlicks.... I have wrote the json where I was having a problem.

Comment: But you apparently haven't read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some services, where you don't know all keys. Obviously you need to know some information about the answer you expect.
In these case we can ask for the keys to the dictionary and work´s with them.
In your case:

```
NSDictionary *first=[json objectForKey:@"query"];
NSDictionary *second=[first objectForKey:@"pages"];

NSArray *allPages = [second allKeys];
for (NSString *key in allPages)
{
    id objectExpect = [second valueForKey:key];
    // do what do you want ...
}
```